# atualizar listview automaticamente quando um novo dado é inserido no banco

Tags: android

Eu criei um webservice e o aplicativo e tudo esta funcionado certinho, porém eu gostaria que meu aplicativo atualize a listview assim que um novo dado é inserido no banco (esse dado pode vir de outro dispositivo) e gostaria que enviasse uma notificação também, porém, o meu problema esta em atualizar a listview, eu acho que devo criar um AsyncTask ou um Service, porém, já li sobre eles mas estou tendo dificuldade pra entende-los e utiliza-los, então, existe alguma outra forma de fazer esta atualização da list sem o uso do AsyncTask ou Service, caso não tenha, alguém tem um bom exemplo para me passar?

Eu tenho um aplicativo que me mostra as tarefas que devo fazer hoje, e essas informações estão armazenadas em um banco de dados que acesso através de um webservice, porém quando uma nova tarefa é inserida no banco de dados eu tenho que ir no aplicativo e clicar no botão para atualizar a listview e assim aparecer a nova tarefa.

Eu gostaria de quando a nova tarefa fosse inserida no banco o meu app no celular atualizasse a listview automaticamente e exibisse uma notificação ou tocasse um áudio ou vibrasse o celular e etc...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um `ContentProvider` no seu app, para acessar/manipular dados do banco (no lugar de queries direto para a base) e implementar um `CursorLoader` na sua Activity (que vai obter os dados através do ContentProvider) e alterar o adapter da sua ListView para usar os dados desse cursor retornado pelo Loader. Com isso, a ListView vai ficar sempre atualizada pois é criado automaticamente um listener para o banco nessa implementação.

É complicado detalhar todos os passos aqui, pois são vários, então sugiro dar uma olhada nesse curso que explica perfeitamente bem como implementar isso:

https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-data-storage--ud845/